# The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). When I try to start it, I get this issue (it was working the past year, no idea why it suddenly fails - I haven't updated anything):

> The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
>   'homestead' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
>   reason is shown below:
>
> VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
>   run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
>   message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.

Running `VBoxManage --version`  returns this:

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no
>   module
>            available for the current kernel (5.3.0-26-generic) or it failed to
>            load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
>        sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
>
>      You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```
>
> 6.0.10r132072

Running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`  returns this:

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services. vboxdrv.sh: Starting
>   VirtualBox services. vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>   vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what
>   went wrong.
>
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up
>   process, run   /sbin/vboxconfig as root.  If your system is using EFI
>   Secure Boot you may need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv,
>   vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see
>   your Linux system's documentation for more information.

The log file is very large. I pasted it [here](https://pastebin.com/8jdhPj8f).

Any recommendations what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading vagrant from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 and virtualbox to 6.0.16

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with VirtualBox 7.0 which I have been using for many months now on my Ubuntu 22.04.

To solve it, I downloaded the package again from [VirtualBox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and installed it:

```sh
# navigate to where the package has been downloaded
cd Downloads

# install the package
sudo apt install ./virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095\~Ubuntu\~jammy_amd64.deb
```